# Collection not found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Im using Meteorjs with package cultofcoders:grapher, when I’m trying to link two collections Im getting error -

```
Error: Could not find a collection with the name: Products [invalid-collection]
at Linker._validateAndClean (packages/cultofcoders:grapher/lib/links/linker.js:159:23)
```

Below is my code

products/collection.js

```
import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";
import ProductSchema from "./schema"

const Products = new Mongo.Collection("products");
Products.attachSchema(ProductSchema);
Products.attachBehaviour("timestampable");

export default Products;
```

products/link.js

```
import Products from "./collection";
import Categories from "../categories/collection";

Products.addLinks({
    productsCategory:{
        type: "one",
        collection: "Categories",
        field: "category"
    }
});
```

You can find the complete repo at link https://github.com/chidugit/publicapp/tree/master/shoppingcart

No error is triggered when attaching schema, but why is there an error when I am trying to add links?
WHat am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure that `products/collection.js` is properly imported on both, the server side and client side.

Comment: @HarryAdel, it has been imported on client and server. I can even insert data into collection

Comment: Could you please provide the config for `Categories` collection? And maybe a repo to a mini version of your project so we can better debug this issue.

Comment: @HarryAdel, you can find the complete repo at link https://github.com/chidugit/publicapp/tree/master/shoppingcart

Comment: The repo lacked `.meteor` and `package.json` so I had to improvise. I cloned this [boilerplate](https://github.com/CaptainN/meteor-react-starter), added your files and removed all unnecessary files. And lo and behold it works! But ofc this is absolutely not accurate without your own packages setup and whatnot. So please, make sure the example is proper, working and represent your actual setup. Here's the [repo](https://github.com/harryadelb/shoppingcart-app-bug) I worked on.